# Power BI dealing with 16gb CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv, powerbi

I have a 16GB CSV that I have imported into Power BI desktop. The workstation I am using is an Azure VM running Windows Server 2016 (64GB Memory). The import of the file takes a few seconds, however, when I try to filter the data set in query editor to a specific date range, it takes a fairly long time (it is still running and has been around 30 minutes so far). The source file (16GB CSV) is being read from a RAM disk that has been created on the VM.

What is the best approach/practice when working with data sets of this size? Would I get better performance importing the CSV in SQL server and then using direct query when filtering the data set to a date range? I would have thought it would run fairly quickly with my current setup as I have 64GB memory on available on that VM.

Comment: That's why you need to pre-aggregate data.

Comment: Note: "Big data" is commonly considered more than a single server to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the data size is significant, you also need appropriate computing power to process it. When you **import** these rows in Power BI, the Power BI itself needs this computing power. If you import the data in SQL Server (or in Analysis Services, or other), and you use Direct Query or Live Connection, you can delegate computations to the database engine. With Live Connection all your modeling is done on the database engine, while in Direct Query modeling is also done in Power BI and you can add computed columns and measures. So if you you Direct Query, you still must be careful what is computed where.

You ask for "the best", which is always a bit vague. You must decide for yourself depending on many other factors. Power BI is Analysis Services by itself (when you run Power BI Desktop you can see the Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services child process running), so importing the data in Power BI should give you similar performance as if it was imported in SSAS. To improve the performance in this case, you need to tune your model. If you import the data in SQL Server, you need to tune the database (proper indexing and modeling).

So to reach a final decision you must test these solutions, consider pricing and hardware requirements and depending on that, decide what is the best for your case.

Recently, Microsoft made a [demo with 1 trillion](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/businessapplicationssummit/video/BAS2018-2172) rows of data. You may want to take a look at it. I will also recommend to take a look at [aggregations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-aggregations), which could help you improve the performance of your model.

Comment: Link to the MS demo doesn't work anymore.